# Wordpress add taxonomies/terms list as a menu in archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, themes, taxonomy, terms

I create a custom post type (deals), terms (project), menu (top_menu) and archive page (archive-deals.php) on my theme. I want to display terms post list in archive page. But when I click terms menu then redirect following link: http://localhost/wordpress/chorui/project/html-3/ and show error message page not found.

```
<?php 
// Custom post and terms 
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'deals',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Deals' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Deal' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true    
        )
    );
}

register_taxonomy("project", array("deals"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Project Types", "singular_label" => "Project Type", "rewrite" => true));
?>


    <?php 
// archive-deals.php

get_header(); 

                                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                                            'theme_location' => 'top_menu',
                                            'container' => 'nav',
                                            'container_class' => 'top_menu',
                                            'fallback_cb' => false,
                                            'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>'
                                        ));

 /* Start the Loop */
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

//This will return the content of the CPT archive

get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format());                   

 endwhile; 

  if ( function_exists('wp_bootstrap_pagination') ) {
    wp_bootstrap_pagination();
}

 get_footer(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the archive by the term,  you should go with [taxonomy template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/).

For you it will be `taxonomy-project.php`

When you work with custom post type , you should update the permalink structure when you make changes on templates,  I mean register new post type or create new template file